# Return two rows as a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL DDL below:

```
create table dbo.Test(id int, name varchar(30))

INSERT INTO Test values (1, 'Mark') 
INSERT INTO Test values (2,'Williams')
```

I am trying to return: 'Mark Williams' using an SQL SELECT.  I have tried using an SQL Pivot, but it has not worked.

Comment: pivot would take your 1 column/2 records table and return is as a 2 column/1 record result set.

Comment: Have you got this scenario in you application development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly more flexible than COALESCE would be to use the STUFF and FOR XML pattern:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Test 
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) Concatenated
 FROM TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Return VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Return = COALESCE(@Return+' ','') + name
FROM dbo.TEST

SELECT @Return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @NameList VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @NameList = COALESCE(@NameList + ' ', '') + Name 
FROM Test
SELECT @NameList
```

Read more [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)